# How to insert code in posts on devices where backtick characters are not supported?

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

I often use my mobile Lumia to access Stack Exchange and answer posts.  The one problem I face is the keyboard on my mobile does not have a `` ` `` (backtick) character so I am not able to format text like `` `this` `` in my code.

Is there some alternate way to get these quotes? I'm not sure if there's an alternate way to do the same thing in HTML.

I read the [formatting tips](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), but couldn't find alternate ways of formatting code.  Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: Try <code>add code here</code>

Comment: Did you try pressing apostroph for about 1-2 seconds? It should open a menu with some more options.

Comment: @ralZarek damn..that works :-D.. Can you post that as an answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character is called a [Grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) but known to programmers as a backtick.

That said, [I couldn't find anything](http://www.google.com?q=lumia%20backtick) that indicates how to enter the backtick on a Lumia device.

However, [the Stack Exchange sites honor the `<code>` HTML element](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/140951); enclosing backticks is just shorthand that Markdown uses to represent the same thing.

It's more typing, unfortunately but it will be honored.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: @MukulGoel No problem.

Answer (score 2):

Backtick can be done on a Lumia by holding down the single quote character. (Similar to getting a `?` by holding down `.`)

Just saw someone posted this as a comment - sorry!